# Declare local variable when defining a function to mimic Table[]

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions

**The problem:**
I want to define a function `tab` to replace the long line

```
Table[f[i,j,k,l],{i,3},{j,3},{k,3},{l,3}]
```

by a shorter line

```
tab[f[i,j,k,l],i,j,k,l]
```

Then I need to declare `i,j,k,l` in `tab` to be local variables, just like in `Table`.

**My trial:**

```
tab[f_, jlist__] := Module[{jlist2 = {jlist}, jlist3}, 
 jlist3 = Sequence @@ ({#1, 3} & ) /@ jlist2; 
  Table[f, Evaluate[jlist3]]]
```

Then I succeeded in

```
(*Input := *) tab[h[i, j], i, j]
(*Output:=  {{h[1, 1], h[1, 2], h[1, 3]}, {h[2, 1], h[2, 2], h[2, 3]},  {h[3, 1], h[3, 2], h[3, 3]}}*)
```

whose output is the same as from `Table[h[i,j],{i,3},{j,3}]`. But I failed in

```
(*Input := *) tab[(f[i, j] = g[i, j]), i, j]
(* {{g[1, 1], g[1, 2], g[1, 3]}, {g[2, 1], g[2, 2], g[2, 3]}, {g[3, 1], g[3, 2], g[3, 3]}} *)
```

in which `f[i,j]=g[i,j]` is evaluated first. I wanted it to behave as `Table[f[i,j]=g[i,j],{i,3},{j,3}]`.

---

**Update:** Below rcollyer's answer leads to the correct output by using `SetAttributes[tab,HoldAll]` first. However, I still want to know if I can declare `i` and `j` as local variables. So far they are not local variables and I would have errors like:

```
(*Input :=*) i=3; tab[f[i],i]
(* Error message "Table::itraw: Raw object 3 cannot be used as an iterator. >>"
  Output:= Table[f[i], {3, {0, 1, 2, 3}}] *)
```

Can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html), or [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldFirst.html):

```
ClearAll[tab];
SetAttributes[tab, HoldAll];
tab[f_, jlist__] := 
 Module[{jlist2 = {jlist}, jlist3}, 
  jlist3 = Sequence @@ ({#1, 3} & ) /@ jlist2; 
  Table[f, Evaluate[jlist3]]
 ]

tab[(f[i, j] = g[i, j]), i, j]
(*
{{g[1, 1], g[1, 2], g[1, 3]}, 
 {g[2, 1], g[2, 2], g[2, 3]}, 
 {g[3, 1], g[3, 2], g[3, 3]}}
*)
```

Note, to clear everything from the definition of `tab`, you will need to use [`ClearAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClearAll.html), as [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clear.html) does not cover `Attributes`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I want. I still wonder if we can make `i` and `j` in `tab[f[i,j],i,j]` local variables? Just like in `Table[f[i,j],{i,3},{j,3}]` the variables `i` and `j` are made special as local variables, and these variables appear in blue color (in ver9.0.4).

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this function built-in and called `Array`?

```
Array[f, {2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{f[1, 1], f[1, 2]}, {f[2, 1], f[2, 2]}}
> ```

```
Array[(f[##] = g[##]) &, {2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{g[1, 1], g[1, 2]}, {g[2, 1], g[2, 2]}}
> ```

```
?? f
```

> ```
> f[1,1]=g[1,1]
> f[1,2]=g[1,2]
> f[2,1]=g[2,1]
> f[2,2]=g[2,2]
> ```

Comment: `Array` is good to get a tensor in a compact way. But it is not good to keep tracking the indices of tensors in computation. For example, if I want to compute $C^{ijk}_{p}=\sum_{lmn}A^{ijk}_{lmn}B^{lmn}_{p}$, with all indices running over the same range, then `mySum[A[i,j,k][l,m,n]B[l,m,n][p],l,m,n]` would be more convenient then `Array`.

Comment: @9527 You can keep track of the indices with `#, #2, #3` corresponding to the dimmensions of an array. I think so, I'm not sure, I have not got much experience with multi indices tensors operations :)

Comment: yes, you are right. For $C^{ijk}_{p}=\sum_{lmn}A^{ijk}_{lmn}B^{lmn}_{p}$, I can use `tensorC=TensorContract[tensorA,TensorB,{{4,1},{5,2},{6,3}}]`, which is efficient and compact. But we need to figure out the pairs `{{4,1},{5,2},{6,3}}` correctly first. It would be still good to keep tracking the indices by writing them down explicitly in many cases though.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables in Mathematica come in some variants so you'd actually have to specify what kind of local variables you want to create (see other questions about `Block`, `Module` and `With` for details, note that all of them have their peculiarities). As far as I understand, you just want to ensure that global definitions don't cause errors with your `tab` definition, for that it is sufficient to ensure that nothing is evaluated too early and let `Table` do the localization. Here is one way to achieve that:

```
ClearAll[tab];
SetAttributes[tab, HoldAll];
tab[body_, varnames__] := Module[{iter = Replace[Hold[varnames], v_ :> {v, 3}, {1}]},
  Table @@ Join[Hold[body],iter]
]
```

you can try what happens without applying `Table` to see how this works.

As for the syntax highlighting you would need to define a corresponding `SyntaxInformation` for `tab`. Here is something that seems to work, but honestly I'm not sure whether there is something better than the `"Integrate"`-type I used, the usual candidates for local variables need iterator like lists for the highlighting to work. Maybe you'll find more information about writing a better `SyntaxInformation` elsewhere:

```
SyntaxInformation[tab] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, __}, 
  "LocalVariables" -> {"Integrate", {2,Infinity}}};
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. That is the "local variable" I want. And the syntax highlighting works for me.